# What is the best solution to avoid page refresh on page scroll?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

After certain page is loaded and when we scroll through the page the page gets refreshed automatically. How to prevent the page refresh on scrolling?

Here is the snippet of code, where after searching a certain value, the page gets loaded and when scrolled drown the page,it gets refreshed and back to the initial phase.

```
 $('#searchBtn').on("click",function(event){    
            var tabValue = $.urlParam('tab');
            if(tabValue== null || tabValue == '1') {
                window.location = 'EmployeesData?tab=1'+'&userrole='+userrole1;
                }
                else if(tabValue!= null && tabValue == '2'){
                    window.location = 'EmployeesData?tab=2'+'&userrole='+userrole1;
                }
});
```

Tried with event.preventDefault(), to avoid the page refresh but no use

Comment: It would be really helpful if you share some code or create a snippet for us to test your problem.

Comment: what you mean with "page refresh on scrolling"? maybe you mean the page jumps to top when completely loaded, after you have already scrolled down?